# Communicate between Android phones using GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new in android development. I'm trying to develop an app in which a user can send a request to another device running the same app and  it should return a response/notification to the sending device.

I googled it and found that GoogleCloudMessaging can be used for that. But all the tutorials say that it can be used to send messages from server to apps. I need to know how the reverse can be done, ie send messages from app to server..

Please provide some tutorial.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: There are two types service GCM and other XMPP, first one is device to cloud, and the second one is both way service. Read about that

Comment: @Saqib Thanks for your reply..I'll try to google it..If u have any tutorials please suggest..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send data to your server, you can use rest communication.
[Here a tutorial](http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/73189/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-Android-Application-in-less-than-15-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Call a server side script**(REST api/ Webserices)** from your android application using **HttpPost/HttpGet**,

**Step 2:** Wait for response coming from server and use it.

Note: don't forget send all **needful data** for your request from your app to server by httppost.

Go through these link this will help you.

[Get started with push notifications in Mobile Services](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139).

[Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
.

[Google android doc on GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html),

[Google Cloud Messaging GCM for Android and Push Notifications](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/)

Comment: Yhanks for your effort..But these tutorials again teach only to send messages from server. I actually want the reverse of it..Pleas help..@Lavekush

Comment: please review answer again.